# WPF/XAML: Image.Source binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Why doesn't this work?

Some Usercontrol (name: myUserControl) with an image control (name: myImage):

UserControl.cs>

```
...
public ImageSource MyImageSource{get;set;}
...
```

UserControl.xaml.cs>

```
...
<Image Name="myImage" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=MyImageSource}" />
...
```

When i use this custom usercontrol and set the value of 'MyImageSource' (i can browse for an image).
But when i build and run, i see nothing.
Did i do the binding correctly?

Comment: Do you actually have the `x:Name=""` property on your user control?  It might be helpful to post a little more of the XAML and the code which sets your MyImageSource property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property needs to be implemented with [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) or it has to be a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx), in a UserControl you usually use dependency properties.